Reducing Power Dissipation in BCR420 Driver
I have a 30V DC power supply, and I want to power an LED strip consisting of 10 RGB LED modules (part number L1MC-RGB0028000MP0) in series. I am using three BCR420 LED drivers to set the current of each color to 20mA, with dimming capability by applying PWM signals to each IC's EN pin.
The issue is that the red LED has a much lower forward voltage drop compared to the green and blue LEDs. As a result, the BCR420 driving the red color has to dissipate more power.
My question is: Can I place a resistor (R4 in the below diagram) in series with the red LEDs to dissipate some of the heat and reduce the power dissipated by the BCR420?


Yes.
Make sure there is enough voltage headroom for your BCR420 at max current and minimum input voltage after adding your resistor.
